# Validation Generator with Previously Split Data Keras

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras

I have three dataframes for training, validation, and testing of an ML program. They were split from a pandas dataframe which read a csv. Here is a sample of that file:

```
id,label
904797024fe2c8ebe4c12f54baf34c62c05ec1ff,1
0ad0a93569e96a95ed1e777b983452e9dbd445f9,0
```

The ID is the filename for an image without the extension, `.tif`.

Previously, I had the training and the validation data in the same dataframe, but to avoid variance, I separated the parts into two dataframes.

Here is my previous code:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                  validation_split = 0.1)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

train_val_path = "../input/train/"

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
                dataframe = df_train_val,
                directory = train_val_path,
                x_col = "id",
                y_col = "label",
                subset = "training",
                target_size = (96, 96),
                batch_size = 32,
                class_mode="binary",
                validate_filenames=False
                )

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = df_train_val,                                                     directory = train_val_path,
                                                        x_col = "id",
                                                        y_col = "label",
                                                        subset = "validation",
                                                        target_size = (96, 96),
                                                        batch_size = 32,
                                                        class_mode="binary",
                                                        validate_filenames=False
                                                        )
```

As you can see in the first line, the `ImageDataGenerator` has a validation split of 0.1. How would I adapt this code to make it work, if I have already conducted this split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the validation split is 0.0 ie no samples are taken for validation.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255) # Not required

train_val_path = "../input/train/"

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
                dataframe = df_train_val,
                directory = train_val_path,
                x_col = "id",
                y_col = "label",
                subset = None,         # Because validation split is not specified
                target_size = (96, 96),
                batch_size = 32,
                class_mode="binary",
                validate_filenames=False
                )

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = df_train_val,   # Pass test dataframe                                                     directory = train_val_path,
                                                        x_col = "id",
                                                        y_col = "label",
                                                        subset = None,       # Because validation split is not specified
                                                        target_size = (96, 96),
                                                        batch_size = 32,
                                                        class_mode="binary",
                                                        validate_filenames=False
                                                        )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just to clarify, the correct values will be passed by the validation generator into the fit function, even if it doesn't have the "validation" subset, and the validation splitpercentage is not specified, right?

Comment: I assume you have two separate dataframe for train and validation. So for val_generator pass val_df and for train_generator pass train_df. Your dataframe cannot be same for both the generators else they will generate the same values.